# Web Push API - Send notifications to multiple recipients

Tags: push-notification, web-push, push-api

Using the W3C Web Push API is it possible to send a push notification in batch so it is received by multiple users ?
When subscribing a user agent for notification we obtain a unique endpoint such as:

```
endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/eAViP691.......
```

So if I want to send the same push to 1000 users, does it mean I need to make 1000 HTTP post requests to the push service ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the Push API directly, in order to reach N devices, you need to make N requests.

Otherwise you can use a web push service that does the work for you: that  allows you to target thousands of user IDs with one API request or reach a segment using tags expressions.

Comment: Thanks pushpad looks nice ! But as it supports the Web Push API under the hood it is probably making a request for each push.

Comment: @WillOge Yes exactly: you make one API request to Pushpad, and then Pushpad, under the hood, makes one HTTP request for each device that must be reached

Comment: Thanks @collimarco ! Going to have a look at Pushpad API.